# Does the ARM v6 have enough power to be a Monero node?

Tags: monerod, nodes, raspberry-pi, helium-hydra

I have compiled Helium Hydra, Point Release 1 on a Raspberry Pi first model powered by ARM v6. It took about 10 hours to compile all, but now it's fully working and I'm able to use it like a Monero node for my LAN.

The problem is that Monero daemon isn't able to stay in sync, every time it remains behind the blockchain for nearly 500 blocks. Internet connection is fine, the Pi is connected by Ethernet and the daemon on another PC works fine and fast.

With 'top', I can see that CPU usage is fixed over 92%, so it's possible that the Raspberry Pi hasn't enough power to handle a Monero node. Should I consider to switch to something more powerful, like a Raspberry Pi Model 3?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Is the miner on ?

Comment: No, not mining.

Comment: Ya so looks like it can't keep up. Keep in mind that over time blocks are getting bigger as there are more and more transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Monero Reddit people, I solved the issue. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7oqrjm/does_the_arm_v6_have_enough_power_to_be_a_monero/) is the link to the discussion.

The issue was related to **timezones** because the timezone of the system was set on wrong timezone, one hour behind the correct one. So, I changed timezone with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and restarted the Pi.

After a long time, the node completed the blockchain synchronization and now it's fully functional. I can access it from all the devices on the LAN, but all the operation are really slow.

So, to answer the question of the title, the **Raspberry Pi Model 1** has enough power to run Monero daemon software, but not enough to be a Monero node in a real world because any operation takes too much time to be completed.

Comment: That's awesome - glad it was able to be verified!

Comment: Also, adding ```--block-sync-size 1``` as daemon startup flag makes all more responsive and fast. It's pretty much usable now.